# How do I change the URL of a SoapHttoClientProtocol object?

Tags: c#, soap

I received some code from a client containg a wsdl.exe generated `SoapHttpClientProtocol` sub-class for us to access. I altered the code as follows:

```
public WebService(string url, bool useDefaultCredentials)
{
   this.Url = url;
   this.UseDefaultCredentials = useDefaultCredentials;
}
```

The client changed the URL for the web-service so we changed the config to match, unfortunately it still appears to be hitting the old URL.

The code contains several attributes referencing the old web service. Specifically a `WebServiceBindingAttribute` with a `Namespace` parameter set to the old .asmx file and a `SoapDocumentMethodAttribute` with the `Action` parameter set to the old URL and the `RequestNamespace` parameter set to the old .asmx file. Could these be the problem?

Comment: Your altered constructor looks right to me. Have you stepped into the code to verify the Url property gets set as expected and isn't changed by other code before the network call is invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update from the client: It looks like in addition to changing the location of the webservice, they also changed the Namespaces of the SOAP methods which broke the auto-generated `[SoapDocumentMethod]` attribute.